# How to display last line from bash MINGW console in a top transparent box in Windows?

Tags: windows, bash

I have a server running from bash command line (MINGW). To see what is going on i need to switch to the console window.

Is it possible on Windows to display last message from console in transparent bar top-most so it will be easy to read?

Comment: use transparent terminal, and move it to the top of screen and set always on top.

Comment: @IporSircer Nice idea. How can i get transparent terminal?

Comment: Try a search engine, for example google: https://www.google.com/search?q=transparent+terminal+windows

Comment: @ipor thank you for the link to Google search results, i was testing glass before and it does not work, also first search result is about windows 10 and i have 7. Also these other tools are not i ask for. I really would like to have an answer from a person who knows how to do it